# Handling raw PDF source in ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, actionscript

I am using the JODConverter web service to convert an ODT-document to a PDF-file. I have some working Ruby code, that will load up the ODT-file and convert it using the web service. The resulting PDF-file is then returned to me and I can easily save it.

When I try to do the same thing in ActionScript, I seem to be facing some issues with FlateDecode blocks in the PDF source. They are somehow altered (possibly because ActionScript strings are UTF-8). The result is that the resulting PDF-file is incomplete. Meta-information is correct, but the file appears to be blank.

I would appreciate any kind of feedback relating to this issue.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you reviewed the alivePDF code?  It generates PDFs via ActionScript and may be a resource http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/

Comment: I'm pretty sure that ActionScript uses utf-16 internally - certainly not utf-8. Curiously, I think most Javascript implementations use utf-32 internally. Not sure if that helps you in any way, but it might be something to go on.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I have asked this question in the AlivePDF forum. I certainly hope someone there can help.

@troelskn You are probably right about it being utf-16. I am not sure that is the real reason behind this though, but I will try to investigate further.

Comment: get first blocks from ruby and AS and compare them, to et know exactly the right encoding.